# Only outside of a figure, nothing on the inside, how do i do that?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

i want only the outside of a figure so i can use it to fill it with particles. (i am a blender newbie) I downloaded a figure from Daz and successfully removed all the materials and vertex groups so i have only one material. Except for the eyes. I tried to join geometry, did not work, boolean did not work or at least how i used it.
To be clear; i just want the outside of the figure and nothing inside (like part of the eyeballs that are inside the figure)
How would you solve this?

Comment: Hello you need to bridge the eyes meshes with the body

Comment: Thank you for your response, how do i do that?

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can try? Also it would be interesting to test boolean to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.